# Android wear: calling a "default fitness app" from java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have a function in my App for Android Wear to call the "default Fitness App"...
I already see in a WatchFace that it is possible tapping on an element to call the App to display a statistic of heart rate or steps count or similar.
If I change the App (for example from Google Fit to Moto Body), and I tap again on the element the new App will be started.

So it **must** be possible to call an action (Intent?) with some value and Android call the properly App.
I searched this "some value" but I didn't found anything. I'm sure, it exists...

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot
Luca

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and debugging other Apps, I found a solution...
I post it here in the case someone other needs it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Fitness.ACTION_VIEW, null);
intent.setType("vnd.google.fitness.data_type/com.google.heart_rate.bpm");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
try
{
  startActivity(intent);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
  Log.v(PROGRAM, "Unable to start Fitness App\n" + e.toString());
}
```

Regards
Luca